# предупреждение: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous

Tags: c++, qt

Почему предупреждение у такого кода ?

```
   QStringList PlotName;
   PlotName << QString("Контуры пятна. С момента растекания прошло %1 мин.").arg(ui->spinBox_7->value(), 0, 'f', 0)
            << "Протяжённость пятна"
            << "Ширина пятна";

предупреждение: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
         PlotName << QString("РљРѕРЅС‚СѓСЂС‹ РїСЏС‚РЅР° Р·Р°РіСЂСЏР·РЅСЏСЋС‰РµРіРѕ РІРµС‰РµСЃС‚РІР°. РЎ РјРѕРјРµРЅС‚Р° РЅР°С‡Р°Р»Р° СЂР°СЃС‚РµРєР°РЅРёСЏ Р—Р’ РїСЂРѕС€Р»Рѕ %1 РјРёРЅ.").arg(ui->spinBox_8->value(), 0, 'f', 0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки и разбейте построчно. А то так даже не понятно, какой фрагмент вызывает ошибку.

Comment: @VTT Ошибка в  строке PlotName << QString("Контуры пятна. С момента растекания прошло %1 мин.").arg(ui->spinBox_7->value(), 0, 'f', 0) . Я привел полный текст. PrintScreen добавил.